# How to create a table in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a table in JS and show it in the page but it does not seem to work. I have two functions, the first one to actually create the table and the second one to order the elements in the table. I tried creating a simple div in html with id `showlist` but the table does not appear in the page. Please see the code below.

```
function myfunction() {
  var array2 = [];
  var list = "<table border ='1'>";
  array2.sort(order);

  list = list + "<tr>";
  list = list + "<td colspan = '2'> TABLE </td>";
  list = list + "</tr>";
  list = list + "<tr>";
  list = list + "<td> PRICE</td>";
  list = list + "</tr>";

  for (i = 0; i <= array2.length; i++) {
    list = list + "<tr>";
    list = list + "<td>" + array2[i].name + "</td>";
    list = list + "<td>" + array2[i].price + "</td>";
    list = list + "</tr>";
  }
  list = list + "</table>";
  $("#showlist").html(list);
}

function order(n1, n2) {
  if (n1.price > n2.price) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    if (n1.price < n2.price) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `array2` is an empty array.......

Comment: @PranavCBalan sorry I forgot to add the other array that is actually an array of objects.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stack snippet

Comment: The for loop should be `for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {`. `<=array.length` would make one iteration and throw undefined error.

Comment: @ShaunakD That's exactly how is written above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the `condition`, `for ( init; condition; increment ) {`, it should be `<` and *not* `<=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop `<=` runs from `0` to `array2.length`, it should be `<` - from `0` to `array2.length-1`.

```
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
//            ^_ Notice change here
   ...
}
```

Else, the last iteration would throw undefined errors.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

---

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e5wnep96/8/)**